# Detect font changes on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following `viewcontroller`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var dogs = ["Dog1", "Dog2","Dog3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dogs.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
     cell.testLabel.text = dogs[indexPath.row]
     return cell
}
}
```

and the following `CustomCell`

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait)
    {
       testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 10)
    }
    else
    {
        testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Italic", size: 25)
    }
   }
}
```

I am observing font changes initially when the `viewcontroller` is accessed but not when I am rotating the device.For example, if the device is in `portrait` and I access the `viewcontroller`, I am getting the correct font but if I change it to `landscape`, it is still showing `portrait` font.

Similarly, if I go to another `viewcontroller` and access the `present` `viewcontroller` in `landscape`, it is showing correct font and when I change the orientation to `portratit`, it is still remembering the `landscape` font. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem, you should set `testLabel` `font` in `cellForItemAt` and simply when rotation changes, you just need call `reloadData` for your collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.testLabel.text = dogs[indexPath.row]
    if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait)
    {
       cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 10)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Italic", size: 25)
    }
     return cell
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    YOUR_COLLECTION_VIEW.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Coder221. Will be very grateful if my answer can be marked as right answer ;)

Comment: I have to wait 5 more minutes

Comment: does this work only for iPhone but not for iPad, because it is not detecting iPad device orientation?

Comment: @Coder221, it detects iPad device orientation too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158289/discussion-between-coder221-and-trungduc).